# Genymotion for Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, genymotion

I want to start write apps for android with Visual Studio. I used default emulator (Cordova),but it is too slow. So I find Genymotion, which is faster than Codova. However I can't connect Genymotion to Visual Studio, because Visual Studio use Cordova and I can't choose genymotion device in device list. So anyone know how to fix it.

PS Really sorry to my terrible english language.

Comment: Directly run genymotion and start a device emulation, while doing that Visual Studio must detect the emulator through adb

Comment: Okey, it's works. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same setup, and my Visual Studio deployments were failing with no error, just failing to deploy to my GenyMotion Android.

So I discovered that there is a setting in GenyMotion (Settings -> ADB -> Use custom Android SDK) which MUST be the same as the SDK you are using in Visual Studio (Tools -> Options -> Xamarin Settings -> Android Settings -> Android SDK Location).

Once I changed this, it all "just worked"! And deployed super quick!!!

Answer (score 1):

No, for the moment Genymotion don't have an official plugin for Visual Studio, but you can open a device in Genymotion (like normally we does) and in Visual Studio choose the option "Device" for to run your project (for default the option is "Ripple - Nexus (Galaxy)") and press Ctrl+f5, with this way Visual Studio detect the device open with Genymotion and run your application.

Answer (score 0):

Guy was the same situation. I read an interesting way in this site [Front In Brazil](http://frontinbrazil.com.br/emulando-aplicativos-ioniccordova-no-genymotion/)

Only start the emulator in GenyMotion and then run the command: `ionic run android` and be happy.
Note: My English is worse.